# jQueryUI Slider - Value toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have the following line of code in jQuery:

```
$( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

I'd like to apply `toFixed(2)` to amount deposit. I'm unsure how I can do this in this instance though, can anyone suggest how I might do this.

Thanks

Comment: `toFixed` is a method of a Number object

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate #amount-deposit so toFixed(2) is applied to it

Comment: what type is returned from `$( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" )`?

Comment: ... so `$( "#amount-deposit" ).val(Number($( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" )).toFixed(2))`

Comment: as per answer, parseFloat is probably better to use than Number :p

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value):-

> value()
>
> Returns: **Number**
>
> Get the value of the slider. This signature does not accept any
>   arguments. Code examples: Invoke the method:
>
> var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );

So, all you need to do is:-

```
$( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" ).toFixed(2));
```